# image manipulation widget for PHP

Tags: php, user-interface, image-manipulation

Any recommendations for how to resize & crop images in a PHP web app?  Ideally will integrate into the UI to allow user to upload, preview, then optionally resize and crop.

Thanks,
Graham

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jquery cropping plug-in.

http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html

Answer (score 0):

and here's a [php code to crop an image](http://phparadise.de/php-code/image-editing/crop-image/) (you'll find code to upload an image there as well)...

it even provides for a rough gui to select the cropped area by clicking on the image.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a PHP + JQuery script that looks promising
http://www.webmotionuk.co.uk/php-jquery-image-upload-and-crop-v11/

Comment: If you can answer your own question, why ask in the first place?